# Force the drag-and-drop operation to horizontal only

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to create a custom double-cursor slider only with imageviews and I discovered how to drag the cursor (it is an imageview) but I want to force the drag-and-drop to be possible only  on the horizontal because on this moment the slider's cursor can be dragged anywhere on the screen :D

Any hints ?